# Why has ClamTK stopped working?

Tags: clamav, clamtk

I cannot do virus checks anymore because ClamTK has stopped working. I have removed and added but no joy. Is anybody else having the same issue?
ClamAV won't run in a terminal either.

Ubuntu 21.04 AMD64

Comment: Wouldn't stress about it tbh. There are a number of very good references which support the viewpoint that ClamAV and its TK GUI variant are a waste of processing resources.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1346457/edit) your question and add maybe a screenshot of ClamTK not working as well as any error output you are getting when you run ClamAV?  Thank you!

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463741

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly due to the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1927065 .

ClamAV in Terminal should not be affected, though. (Note that the signatures manually updated with ClamTk and the ones updated automatically with freshclam could be in different directories. The directory can be passed as an option to ClamAV.)